# Using react-spring Parallax, how can I increase an image width as the user scrolls?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, parallax, react-spring

I am making a basic webpage on React with two Parallax Layers with images, the first layer image is a drawing of a room, and the second layer image is a drawing of a doorway, with a transparent cutout where the door is. I plan on doing a bunch of parallax scrolling in the future for this site, and want to use the react-spring package since it has many features I'm keen on using.

As the user scrolls down, I want to zoom and increase the width of the doorway image (yellow box) from the center point, till it is no longer visible and gives way to the room illustration, instead of it scrolling up and disappearing. Essentially, an illusion of entering a room through a door.

Here is the jist of my code on codesandbox, if you scroll you can see some of the react-spring Parallax in effect. I have spent about 12 hours looking for an answer on how to increase the width of the doorframe image (yellow box) as I scroll, and have had no working results. I'm running out of things to Google - I've tried methods with Javascript, where I give the CSS style a variable, Jquery that tracks scroll distance, using Spring native to, and pure CSS and still can't seem to find a solution compatible for the react-spring package.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/practical-sea-2tecb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Since I am trying to use React and the react-spring library, I think I've made this issue complicated. But, as I develop more of the site, I want to be able to use the features on react-spring. Any guidance would be so, so helpful.

Thanks

Comment: My initial tought was that you only need a scroll event listener and based on the position you can change the width of the component. Unfortunately the scroll event do not fired with Parallax. I have no advice for you apart to look at this thread: https://spectrum.chat/react-spring/general/parallax-with-scroll-event-listener~6d40daff-10c3-47a0-bc07-7db5964330e7

Comment: thank you so much for the pointer - i really appreciate it!